What's a term for a graph having the same cycles and number of disconnected subgraphs as another graph?
Graph theory question:
Let $G_a$ be a directed graph generated by $a(S)=G_a$ from a set $S$. The graph may contain some cycles and may not be connected. Let $G_{ab}$ be a subgraph of $G_a$ generated by pruning function $b(G_a)=G_{ab}$, which removes a set of leaf nodes from $G_a$ (the nodes which can be removed without altering the number or length of cycles, and without changing the number of disconnected subgraphs). We can't say $G_{ab}$ is isomorphic to a subgraph of $G_a$ that contains all its disconnected subgraphs and cycles, since a disconnected subgraph in $G_{ab}$ may be shorter in length due to the pruning.
So is there another term besides "isomorphic" that captures this weaker degree of similarity between G_{a} and G_{ab} where their cycles are isomorphic, the number of disconnected subgraphs are the same, and G_{ab} is a subgraph of G_{a}?
Or am I going to have to define some new jargon term for my paper to refer to this kind of similarity?

For directed graphs, the words "connected" and "leaf nodes" are ambiguous; can you clarify their meaning? Also, does "generated by $a(S) = G_a$" mean anything, or is it just "flavor text"?

If the graphs were undirected, I would call $G_{ab}$ a 2-core of $G_a$.
